# How to attach a `Tab Bar Controller` to an existing view of a toolbar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am attaching a `Tab Bar Controller` to an existing view with a toolbar.

However, I am getting the tab bar `controller offset` at the bottom, so you can just see the top of the items. I am using the following to attach the `Tab Bar Controller` to the view:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [self.view insertSubview:dashboardTabController.view atIndex:0];
  }
```

I have attached an image. I hope someone can help as I've been trying to fix this for hours now, and it's driving me crazy.

[Image is available to view at:](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5825/iphonesimulatorscreensn.jpg) 
[alt text http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5825/iphonesimulatorscreensn.jpg](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/5825/iphonesimulatorscreensn.jpg)

Comment: It's an obvious question but what is the frame of your TabBar view?

Comment: ...and your image didn't attach :-)

Comment: There's a containing view which has a navigation bar at the top, that's the frame for the tabbar view. 

P.S. I've now added a link to the image, as for some reason it won't appear on the post :)

Answer (score 1):

add constraint to fix your tabbar at the bottom of the screen